# Prevent AutoScroll When Dragging HTML

Tags: javascript, css, scroll, raphael, drag

I am using raphael to draw items on the screen. I have the container for the drawing object contained in a `div` and `overflow: scroll`. In all broswers **except for** IE 7/8 when the user is drawing it does not scroll. However, in IE 7/8 when the user is dragging (i.e. drawing a line) it scrolls automatically as the user nears the edges. I have found some help with jQuery and have tried overriding the `onscroll` event of the div but that didn't work.

I am not using jQuery and cannot add it.

Comment: Do you only want scroll in one direction? If so, you should be using overflow-x & overflow-y

Comment: The user can scroll in both directions but only while they are not currently drawing (a.k.a. have the mouse "down")

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes scrolling is caused by "selecting" text in the window (click and drag from top to bottom on this SO page to see what I mean). I can't tell from your description if this is the issue without seeing a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) example or sample code, but you might try disabling selection.

As you mentioned jQuery is not an option for you. If it were, you'd just use [`disableSelection()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/disableSelection/).

**For a vanilla Javascript solution, try:**

```
function disableSelection(target) {
    if (typeof target.onselectstart != "undefined") { //IE
        target.onselectstart = function () {
            return false;
        };
    } else if (typeof target.style.MozUserSelect != "undefined") { //Firefox 
        target.style.MozUserSelect = "none";
    } else { //All other ie: Opera
        target.onmousedown = function () {
            return false;
        };
    }
    target.style.cursor = "default";
}

window.onload = function () {
    disableSelection(document.body);
};
```

*Source (slightly modified for clarity): [Disable selection on browser using Javascript](http://www.thedesilva.com/2010/03/disable-selection-on-browser-using-javascript/)*

Comment: I used the same philosophy but instead of stopping the entire select start on the body, I just cleared anything that was selected in the `mousemove` event using `document.selection.empty()`